# How to set up WooCommerce per item shipping cost

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, woothemes

I want to set up shipping cost on per item basis, but in woocommerce plugin I only get 2 options with flat rate (per class basis & per order basis) there is no per item option.
How can i set up per item shipping cost.

[image]

Comment: You can accomplish this, for example by using a custom meta field for the product and hooking into the proper functions to update order items and subtotals in the cart, and to show the extra shipping field in your templates. It's not that difficult if you understand the plugin/theme development process, but if you don't, there's surely a plugin for that.

Answer (score 3):

In flat-rate cost field enter rule like -
10 * [qty]

This will add 10 per item.

For a little bit more advanced options you can try out the following plugin

[Updated link] https://www.pluginhive.com/per-product-add-on-for-woocommerce-shipping-pro/